# Java servlet and javascript get request: multiple requests to the same servlet, updated game state

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, servlets

I have:

- a Java class `Game.java` (contains integers' array representing a game field and a method that updates that field)
- a servlet `StartServlet` (creates a new `Game` instance, updates it 1 time and sends a JSON response with that field)
- and Javascript's function `updateState()` (takes the servlet's
  response and makes changes to the document based on it):

  ```
  public class Game  {
     private int[][] field;

     public Game(int size)  {
       //creates field of int[size][size] and randomly puts 1s and 0s inside
     }

     public void update()  {
       //updates field (1 or 0), depending on some rules
     }

     public String toString()  {
       //returns a String representation of the field array
     }

     public int[][] getField()  {return field;}
  }
  ```

and a Servlet that makes use of the `Game` class:

```
public class StartServlet extends HttpServlet {
     protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        Game game = new Game(15);
        game.update();   

        for (int i=0; i<game.getField().length; i++)  {
          //transfer data from the game's field to JSON
       }

       response.getWriter().println(jsonArray.toString());
     }
}
```

On the front, when a button is clicked, Javascript takes the `JSON` array the `StartSevlet` returns

```
$(document).on("click", "#start-button", function () {  
            //update game's state every second
            var timerId = setInterval(updateState, 1000);

            //do it for 5 seconds  
            setTimeout(function() {  
                clearInterval(timerId);
                alert( 'stop' );
            }, 5000);
});

function updateState()  {
        getResponseField(drawFieldJSON);
}

function getResponseField(callback)  {
    //gets JSON array from the servlet, stores it in Javascript's array

    callback(responseField);
}

function drawFieldJSON(responseField)  {
    //makes appropriate changes to document's divs, depending on the reponse array
}
```

I want to be able to update the game's state in a loop in Javascript, something like this:

```
var timerId = setInterval(updateState, 1000);  //update game's state every second
setTimeout(function() {  //do it for 5 seconds
  clearInterval(timerId);
  alert( 'стоп' );
}, 5000);
```

However, the game doesn't really change, because it's the new request to the servlet each time, and a new `Game` instance is created each time. I'm not sure how to modify it to make it work or if it's even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make Game object   static   in servlet class  `Game game = new Game(15);`
static fields in a serlvet will not only live across all the sessions&request but across the whole application, in this case, until the web application is undeployed.

please try if you face any issue or need any update please comment i will update with code

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I suspected static would help, but wasn't sure how it would fit into the whole servlets thing. However, I have one question: what if I only want the game to be alive, until a page with javascript code is refreshed? Then, after the page is reloaded, I would need a new game object to be created.

Comment: Hi use jquery window.onload = function (e) {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            url: 'url',
            data: {IsRefresh:'createobj'}
        });
    }; // in servlet side service method put condition like if(check request type){ assing new object to game = new Game(15) } in this way you will get new object on each refresh

Comment: I don’t agree with this answer because with static keyword your game object will be same with all clients. All clients’ game object must be specific for them. Jinendra’s answer must be correct. Some code may be provided for clarification. @parsecer

Answer (score 2):

Store Game object in session and for each request get game object from session. So that it will increment for every request